# Get records by First Character Elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, flask-restful

> {
> "settings": {
> "analysis": {
> "tokenizer": {
> "ngram_tokenizer": {
> "type": "ngram",
> "min_gram": 1,
> "max_gram": 2
> }
> },
> "analyzer": {
> "ngram_analyzer": {
> "type": "custom",
> "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
> }
> }
> }
> },
> "mappings": {
> "properties": {
> "ItemID": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "currency": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "description": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "domain": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "id": {
> "type": "long"
> },
> "images": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "main_category": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "name": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "price": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> },
> "fielddata": True
> },
> "rating": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "stock_status": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "sub_category_1": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> },
> "fielddata": True
> },
> "sub_category_2": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> },
> "fielddata": True
> },
> "sub_category_3": {
> "type": "text",
> "fielddata": True
> },
> "testimonials_rating": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> },
> "title": {
> "type": "text",
> "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
> "fielddata": True
> },
> "url": {
> "type": "text",
> "fields": {
> "keyword": {
> "type": "keyword",
> "ignore_above": 256
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }

I want to get all records by first alphabet of search using my own API in python
elastic search query i'm using is

> self.baseQuery = {
> "query": {
> "prefix": {
> "title.keyword": alphabet # Using lower() to handle case-insensitive search
> }
> }
> }

but i'm getting empty records